# Deactivating a tree item in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

When using a QWidgetItem you can use the function: setDisabled() , to grey out a tree item.

I am struggling to figure out how to do this in the context of QTreeView and QAbstractItemModel ?

I have taken a look at all the qt.ItemDataRoles, but none jump out at me as the one used to disable an item.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This controlled by the [flags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) method of the model. Disabled items don't have the [ItemIsEnabled](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum) flag set. If you use a [QStandardItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html), the items have a [setFlags](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setFlags) method.

Comment: I am using a custom datatype.  Do i need to reimplement setFlags or something?